# Breakpoint is not hitting when browse from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have deployed my MVC 3 application in IIS. Is there any possible way that I can debug. Since breakpoint is not hitting when I run from IIS.

Code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{        
    Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionID"].Secure = true;
}
```

Comment: @mjwills -- I have a breakpoint in Global.asax.cs file, Application_BeginRequest method. But when I run application it is not hitting.

Comment: It will never hit the breakpoint because the application is not being debugged. This has been asked before, and the answer is to attach the debugger to the process.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto -- Can you please let me know the steps to attach debugger to the process. If possible please share me the link.

Comment: @Ask_SO the duplicate link contains links to the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are steps in Visual Studio:

1. Click "Debug" from the menu bar
2. Click "Attach to Process"
3. Check the "Show processes from all users" checkbox in the bottom left corner
4. Select aspnet_wp.exe, w3p.exe, or w3wp.exe from the process list
5. Click "Attach"

Answer (score -2):

You deployed in server(local). So it is not possible to debug.

Comment: It **is** entirely possible to debug. You just need to attach the debugger